# Cryptography - Bizzare behaviour in Release mode

Tags: c++, cryptography, release, undefined-behavior, crypto++

I've got a project using [Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/).

Crypto++ is a own project which builds in a static lib.
Aside from that I have another large project using some of the Crypto++ classes and processing various algorithms, which also builds in a static lib.

Two of the functions are these:

```
long long MyClass::EncryptMemory(std::vector<byte> &inOut, char *cPadding, int rounds)
{
    typedef std::numeric_limits<char> CharNumLimit;
    char sPadding = 0;
    //Calculates padding and returns value as provided type
    sPadding = CalcPad<decltype(sPadding)>(reinterpret_cast<MyClassBase*>(m_P)->BLOCKSIZE, static_cast<int>(inOut.size()));
    //Push random chars as padding, we never care about padding's content so it doesn't matter what the padding is
    for (auto i = 0; i < sPadding; ++i)
        inOut.push_back(sRandom(CharNumLimit::min(), CharNumLimit::max()));
    std::size_t nSize = inOut.size();
    EncryptAdvanced(inOut.data(), nSize, rounds);
    if (cPadding)
        *cPadding = sPadding;
    return nSize;
}

//Removing the padding is the responsibility of the caller.
//Nevertheless the string is encrypted with padding
//and should here be the right string with a little padding
long long MyClass::DecryptMemory(std::vector<byte> &inOut, int rounds)
{
    DecryptAdvanced(inOut.data(), inOut.size(), rounds);
    return inOut.size();
}
```

Where `EncryptAdvanced` and `DecryptAdvanced` pass the arguments to the Crypto++ object.

```
//...
AdvancedProcessBlocks(bytePtr, nullptr, bytePtr, length, 0);
//...
```

These functions have so far worked flawless, no modifications have been applied to them since months.
The logic around them has evolved, though the calls and data passed to them did not change.

The data being encrypted / decrypted is rather small but has a dynamic size, which is being padded `if (datasize % BLOCKSIZE)` has a remainder.
Example: AES Blocksize is 16. Data is 31. Padding is 1. Data is now 32.

After encrypting and before decrypting, the string is the same - as in the picture.

[image: Encrypt/Decrypt data]

Running all this in **debug mode** apparently works as intended. Even when running this program on another computer (with VS installed for DLLs) it shows no difference. The data is correctly encrypted and decrypted.

Trying to run the same code in **release mode** results in a totally different encrypted string, plus it does not decrypt correctly - "trash data" is decrypted. The wrongly encrypted or decrypted data is consistent - always the same trash is decrypted. The key/password and the rounds/iterations are the same *all the time.*

Additional info: The data is saved in a file (`ios_base::binary`) and correctly processed in debug mode, from two different programs in the same solution using the same static librar(y/ies).

What could be the cause of this Debug / Release problem ?

<sub>*I re-checked the git history a couple of times, debugged for days through the code, yet I cannot find any possible cause for this problem.* If any information - aside from a (here rather impossible) [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is needed, please leave a comment.</sub>

Comment: Are you sure that AdvancedProcessBlocks() allows in-place transformation?  The documentation says that ProcessBlock() does permit it, but it doesn't explicitly say that AdvancedProcessBlocks() does.

Comment: Does ProcessBlock() exhibit similar Debug/Release behaviour?  The answer to that might yield a clue.

Comment: @Jeremy It does allow it. I've used and debugged it for the previous months without problems. The problems started only recently. So far no-one had any issues with previous versions. I'll look into it later again and check what the possible cause could be (/ update the question). If I remember correctly it only occured on one specific call of the library.

Comment: Look carefully at how you're populating the input vector.

Comment: @Jeremy `fileIFstream.read(vector.data(), vector.size());` where size and (current) file-position match exactly the position and size when they've been encrypted and written to the file. There's a `reinterpret_cast` for `unsigned char*` <---> `char*` when using `vector.data()`.

Comment: Can you post the functions with the removed code included?

Comment: @Jeremy I doubt this is going to help, I've updated the question. The problem appears to be something else. Still debugging it, for the moment it appears to be a key-problem, which STILL is quite odd. The key is set and padded with `'\0'`s in order to have a `GetValidKeyLength(curLength)` (too large = throw...). Then the key is then set to the underlying Cypto++ object. Nothing seems wrong here, but the encrypted & decrypted string is now equal in both Debug & Release. It is only wrongly decrypted in Release mode when one program (of a few) is trying to decrypt it. Calls to libs are the same.

Comment: The reinterpret_cast<MyClassBase*>(m_P) is a big smelly loud flashing red light.

Comment: @Jeremy That might be true if you can't see the code. I'm unable to post all of it. This is 100% of all cases working. I can now confirm that the problem is something with the key in one of the programs. The key is set correctly and apparently inside of Crypto++ something happens -> the key is incorrectly processed/bitshifted. Strange enough this only appears in one of the compiled programs. Not even 32 to 64-bit issues show up. I'll keep investigating this... got no choice.

Comment: *"Trying to run the same code in release mode results in a totally different encrypted string, plus it does not decrypt correctly - "trash data" is decrypted"* - It sounds like a classic memory error. Run a different set of tools on it to get a different view of the error. Or, move to Linux, and try a Sanitizer or Valgrind. For me, there's not enough code available to make an educated guess. You should probably reduce things to a minimal case. If you can reproduce using the minimal case, then post the code.

Comment: *"The data being encrypted / decrypted is rather small but has a dynamic size, which is being padded if (datasize % BLOCKSIZE) has a remainder."* - you should probably use PKCS padding. It handles boundary cases properly, like `SIZEOF(plain text) == 16`.

Comment: @jww I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Having a small test-class using either directly `CryptoPP` or my library results in the same. No error, all fine. Just this specific program apparently does something wrong with the key. The values of the array in the class `Rijndael::Base` -> `m_key` -> `m_alloc` -> `m_array` show for the faulty program `84, 0, ...` where the working test case shows `0, 0, 84, 0, ...`. Basically there is the problem. I'll keep investigating. I'm afraid but the padding has to be handled this way..., thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: @Jeremy Is it normal that the Crypto++ algorithm dereferences an out-of-bounds array ? Inside of `UncheckedSetKey` it apparently dereferences beyond the maximum of the in-place array `rcLE`. There's also a comment next it. `for 128-bit blocks, Rijndael never uses more than 10 rcon values`. This looks like a bug to me, or am I wrong ? This is the point where it apparently fails.

Comment: @Blacktempel - Back up to the library test suite and test vectors. Build the library as usual. Find `cryptest.exe` and copy it to the root of the Crypto++ source files (this is needed because the various data files are expected to be in a certain place; see [Crypto++ DataDir](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Datadir) on the wiki. Moving `cryptest.exe` sidesteps the problem). Open a command prompt, and then run both (1) `cryptest.exe v` and (2) `cryptest.exe tv all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in CryptoPP. The minimum keylength of Rijndael / AES is set to 8 instead of 16. Using a invalid keylength of 8 bytes will cause a out-of-bounds access to the in-place array of Rcon values. This keylength of 8 byte is currently reported as valid and has to be fixed in CryptoPP.

See [this issue on github](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/252) for more information. (On-going conversation)

Comment: Oof, that implementation looks a little careless for a crypto library...
(Easy for me to say from here in my armchair.)
Well done tracking down the problem.